# Why didn't my friend get the achievement for 10 fireworks in 10 seconds?

Tags: achievements, xbox-one, astroneer

My friend and I were both in the same game session, and on the same planet. He launched more than 10 fireworks in under 10 seconds but neither he nor I got the achievement.

So my question is this: Can you light all the fireworks at once or do you have to do each one individually?

Answer (score 1):

According to [True Achievements](https://www.trueachievements.com/a268066/baby-youre-a-firework-achievement) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaglxQ0gjGc):

You can get the achievement by placing 2 fireworks into your top left and right backpack slots, 4 fireworks on the front bumper and 4 on the rear bumper of the large rover.
Not all 10 fireworks are launched together, but it apparently works.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try that out, and thank you for helping me out with my other question.

Comment: No problem, and good luck!